# In how many ways is my crocodile shaped like itself?

Tags: general-topology, functions, cardinals

Here is a topologically accurate photograph of my crocodile:

[image]

In particular, topologically he is a solid sphere. He can be described as being shaped like himself, but that is vague. There are so many ways it can be shaped like himself!

Specifically, I am asking how many homeomorphisms there are from my solid sphere crocodile to itself. I know that, under continuum hypothesis, this quantity is less than or equal to $\aleph_2$. I don't know its exact value though.

Also, without continuum hypothesis or axiom of choice, do we still know this quantity?

Comment: Do you mean _homeomorphisms_ from the crocodile to itself?

Comment: Also, a crocodile is NOT simply connected. If you only consider the digestive track, it looks like  torus.

Comment: When you say "continuum hypothesis", do you mean the _generalized_ continuum hypothesis (since the ordinary CH does not say anything about $\aleph_2$)? And why bring the CH into the picture at all -- if you all you want is to be able to speak about $\beth_2=2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$ you can just use its name without tying everything up to the status of (G)CH.

Comment: Holy obfuscated question, Batman!

Comment: @ArthurFischer (Slap) That's a shakespearean reference, robin!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since your sphere has $|\mathbb R|$ points and contains a countable dense subset (for example, the points with rational coordinates), the number of homeomorphisms cannot be *larger than* $|\mathbb R|$, since any homeomorphism is completely given by its values on a dense subset, so there are at most $$|\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}| = |(2^{\mathbb N})^{\mathbb N}| = |2^{\mathbb N\times\mathbb N}| = |2^{\mathbb N}| = |\mathbb R| $$ continuous functions from the sphere to itself.

On the other hand, there are also *at least* continuum many homeomorphisms, for example the rigid rotations around some axis.

By Cantor-Schröder-Bernstein, then, the number of homeomorphisms is exactly $|\mathbb R|$.

(And this is independent of the continuum hypothesis, the generalized hypothesis, and the Axiom of Choice).